# zend_locale_data: How to add custom / own xml?

Tags: php, xml, locale, addition

I want to add format pattern to format dial numbers as an xml file to the data directory of zend_locale_data. At the moment there are no format patterns available via CLDR, so i want to add it to my local zend framework environment.

As [mentioned here](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2233?focusedCommentId=17700&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-17700), comment of Thomas Weidner at 26/Nov/07 2:04 AM, there is a way, but I can not find the file (file name is not written in that post) in the data directory (not in ZF 1.0.2 or in a newer one: e.g. 1.11.3).

I can not extend the Zend/Locale/Data.php and add a new case "dialnumber" to the switch-case in getContent(), because there are some private vars used (instead of protected) in getContent().

How to add a own "dialNumber.xml"?

Comment: CLDR has a ticket filed on this now: http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/ticket/4092